# Java Draw Image from Int Array

Tags: java, image, image-processing, pixel

If you have an int array representing individual pixels' RGB and Alpha values, how can I turn this into an image? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use `BufferedImage` and `setRGB` method, see [the docs](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) and look for following method:

```
public void setRGB(int startX,
          int startY,
          int w,
          int h,
          int[] rgbArray,
          int offset,
          int scansize)
```

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124630/turn-an-array-of-pixels-into-an-image-object-with-javas-imageio/125013#125013).