# What type of array required in WritableRaster method setPixels()?

Tags: java, javax.imageio, shared-secret

I don't understand how WritableRaster class of Java works. I tried looking at the documentation but don't understand how it takes values from an array of pixels. Plus, I am not sure what the array of pixels consists.

Here I explain.

What I want to do is : Shamir's Secret Sharing on images. For that I need to fetch an image in BuferedImage image. I take a secret image. Create shares by running a 'function' on each pixel of the image. (basically changing the pixel values by something)

Snippet:

```
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
for (int i = 0; i < h; i++) 
    {
    for (int j = 0; j < w; j++) 
        {
        int pixel = image.getRGB(j, i);

        int red = (pixel >> 16) & 0xFF;
        int green = (pixel >> 8) & 0xFF;
        int blue = (pixel) & 0xFF;

        pixels[j][i] = share1(red, green, blue);
```

// Now taking those rgb values. I change them using some function and return an int value. Something like this:

```
public int share1 (r, g, b)
{
a1 = rand.nextInt(primeNumber);
total1 = r+g+b+a1;
new_pixel = total1 % primeNumber;
return new_pixel;
}
```

// This 2d array pixels has all the new color values, right? But now I want to build an image using this new values. So what I did is. 
First converted this pixels array to a list. 
Now this list has pixel values of the new image. But to build an image using RasterObj.setPixels() method, I need an array with RGB values [I MIGHT BE WRONG HERE!]
So I take individual values of a list and find rgb values and put it consecutively in a new 1D array 
pixelvector..something like this (r1,g1,b1,r2,g2,b2,r3,g3,b3...)

Size of the list is w*h because it contains single pixel value of each pixel.
BUT, Size of the new array pixelvector will become w*h*3 since it contains r,g,b values of each pixel..

Then to form image I do this: Snippet

```
BufferedImage image_share1 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster rast = (WritableRaster) image_share1.getData();
rast.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixelvector);
image_share1.setData(rast);
ImageIO.write(image_share1,"JPG",new File("share1.jpg"));
```

If I put an array with just single pixel values in setPixels() method, it does not return from that function! But if I put an array with separate r,g,b values, it returns from the function. But doing the same thing for share1 , share 2 etc.. I am getting nothing but shades of blue. So, I am not even sure I will be able to reconstruct the image..

PS - This might look like a very foolish code I know. But I had just one day to do this and learn about images in Java. So I am doing the best I can.

Thanks..

Comment: rast.setPixels(0, 0, w, h, pixelvector);  

Based on the doc that function is setting the whole image to the color of 'pixelvector'. Here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/WritableRaster.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn an array of pixels into an Image object with Java's ImageIO?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/124630/turn-an-array-of-pixels-into-an-image-object-with-javas-imageio)

Comment: @newObjekt..Yes I know, But as I said I dont understand the documentation. Does it set the entire image by taking 3 values from that array at a time, LIKE: r,g,b or does it take only 1 value .?

Comment: @VinceEmigh Yes, but What I dont understand is the array pixelvector..Should it contain 1 value/ pixel or 3 consecutive values/pixel.??

Comment: Retitle yout question to be more specific. What do you mean *3 consecutive pixels*? The array should contain all the pixels in the image. Do you understand how pixels in a singe dimensional array work? You calculate which pixel is being set using `x + (y * width)` (you dont need to use the formula, im just showing you how you'd pick which pixel to access)

Comment: @VinceEmigh just one last thing: if I want to make an image of w width and h height ..do I need to input an array of size (w*h) in setPixels() method i.e., an array of pixel values.  OR  do I nee to input an array of size (w*h*3) in setPixels() method..HOW is the method going to take values from array pixelvector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Raster` (like `WriteableRaster` and its subclasses) consists of a `SampleModel` and a `DataBuffer`. The `SampleModel` describes the sample layout (is it pixel packed, pixel interleaved, band interleaved? how many bands? etc...) and dimensions, while the `DataBuffer` describes the actual storage (are the samples bytes, short, ints, signed or unsigned? single array or array per band? etc...).

For `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB` the samples will be pixel packed (all 3 R, G and B samples packed into a single `int` for each pixel), and data/transfer type `DataBuffer.TYPE_INT`.

Sorry for not answering your question regarding `WritableRaster.setPixels(...)` directly, but I don't think it's the method you are looking for (in most cases, it's not). :-)

For your goal, I think what you should do is something like:

```
// Pixels in TYPE_INT_RGB format 
// (ie. 0xFFrrggbb, where rr is two bytes red, gg two bytes green etc)
int[] pixelvector = new int[w * h]; 

BufferedImage image_share1 = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
WritableRaster rast = image_share1.getRaster(); // Faster! No copy, and live updated
rast.setDataElements(0, 0, w, h, pixelvector);
// No need to call setData, as we modified image_share1 via it's raster

ImageIO.write(image_share1,"JPG",new File("share1.jpg"));
```

I'm assuming the rest of your code for modifying each pixel value is correct. :-)

But just a tip: You'll make it easier for yourself (and faster due to less conversion) if you use a 1D array instead of a 2D array. I.e.:

```
int[] pixels = new int[w * h]; // instead of int[][] pixels = new int[w][h];

// ...

for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {

        // ...

        pixels[y * w + x] = share1(red, green, blue); // instead of pixels[x][y];
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works and made my code really short and faster. Thanks a lot. One more thing, can you tell me if my share1 method is correct? What I want to do is get the Red, green, blue values of the original pixel and then call share1..in that, I add and multiple random things and return a new_pixel value..BUT, the old pixel values are like -60000 or so and new pixel values are like 150 or 200..Is it correct? I need to return back a packed RGB pixel value.I am supposed to get back noise-like images!! which I am not!!

Comment: Good! :-) I don't know the algorithm you are trying to implement here, so it's hard to say for sure. But it *looks* a little strange for me to just sum up `r`, `g` and `b`. Maybe you should compute each value on its own, and then re-create the packed RGB format using `int newPixel = 0xff000000 | (r & 0xff) << 16 | (g & 0xff) << 8 | (b & 0xff);`?

Comment: Well, I am trying to encrypt image (Shamir's Secret Sharing)/ For that I have to run a function which maps R, G, B values to only one value, which is the color of a pixel of encrypted image. (They are supposed to be gray noise-like). The func is = (R + G + B + a) mod prime. [a is a random no]. NOW, this function wants me to sum the RGB values..weird... so I cant do your approach..

Comment: I see... Well, I skimmed the Wikipedia article, but it's too technical for me to understand in 30 seconds... ;-) So I suggest you ask another question on that specifically. But I can't see how this method can create anything but a greenish-blue image (or blue if `prime` is lower than 255). Maybe (`val` = result of func) `int newPixel = 0xff000000 | (val & 0xff) << 16 | (val & 0xff) << 8 | (val & 0xff);` then? This should at least create gray noise. Or you need to make sure that prime is between 255 * 255 and 255 * 255 * 255. That could work